# Why does cognos takes so much time to install?

Tags: configuration, cognos-10

Why does cognos takes so much time to install? Why does it need high-end configuration?

I admit that cognos is an awesome tool to generate reports with but after installing it,my laptop became very slow.

And also when I'm installing cognos, my database didn't work.... Is it because of cognos under installation or some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

Cognos works according to you system capacity, if your system configuration is low then your system will become slow. And we are installing cognos server with the installation tool, usually whenever we install a server on normal systems then our systems will become slow. Consider that you need to have atleast 8gb of RAM inorder to play with cognos. The systems which lower configuration than this will become slow.